# After upgrade Spring Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE to 2.3.2.RELEASE service isn't working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my spring boot microservices run currently with Spring-Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I also still use

- Spring-Cloud Hoxton.SR7

  - spring-cloud-starter-sleuth 2.2.4
  - spring-cloud-starter-zipkin 2.2.4
  - spring-boot-starter-data-rest 2.2.9
  - spring-boot-starter-quartz 2.2.9
  - spring-boot-configuration-processor 2.2.9
  - spring-boot-starter-web 2.2.9
  - spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client 2.2.4
  - spring-boot-starter-actuator 2.2.9
  - spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.2.9
- PostgreSQL
- Logstash 6.4
- Logbook 2.1.4
- Lombok 1.18.12

dependencies.

Now I wanted switch to Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE. I can compile the code without any errors. After start the service I see this

INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

log message. There are now errors. And then the deployment process stopped. Nothing happens.

At the moment I have no idea why it's not running. Has someone some tip?

Comment: Whole console output please

Comment: @JAsgarov here ist the log ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cHkR_8A2MJhemagJcA4SE39T4fD3LsS4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JAsgarov can you see something in the log?

Comment: not really, did the application crash? where is the crash message?

Comment: @JAsgarov this is my problem. There is no exception ... the Application is still running, but looks like "zombi" state. I try to evaluate this on weekend. thx!

Comment: @JAsgarov I checked my code with the new Spring Boot Starter 2.3.3 and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR8. Still the same. I generated the working log (Spring Boot Starter 2.2.9, Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR8) and the not working log (Spring Boot Starter 2.3.3, Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR8).

The last line in the now working log is

o.h.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured

And in the working log the next line is:

o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Comment: @JAsgarov I put the logs here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19uvS_zxgHqJc2uPMFUzvDI8nfa7d5SYp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class AccountApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Than I used the Exceutor in my code:

```
   @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
   public CompletableFuture<ServiceAccountDTO> registerAccountInService(final String uuid, final ServiceEnum serviceEnum,
                                                                             final Date creationDate, final Date realCreationDate) {
    ..
    }
```

With this configuration the service was not starting correctly.

Now the @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor") configuration is removed and I'm using only @Async.

But why it's not working with Spring Boot Starter 2.3.x? And there was no error message in  the log.